# How to test async code using XCTestCase

Tags: ios, unit-testing, asynchronous

I have a call out to a restful API.  I need to wait for the call to complete before I can validate the results.  Pretty common problem yet I cannot find a decent answer on how to incorporate this into an XCTestCase.  I have seen semaphores, locks, for loops all cluttering up code to run what should be a simple case.  Running iOS 7 in xcode 5.

There has to be an easier option.

Comment: You may take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776943/unit-testing-parse-framework-ios/21778069#21778069

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now use XCTestExpectation. Tutorial available on NSHipster: [nshipster.com/xctestcase](http://nshipster.com/xctestcase)